# Infopath, sharepoint list and SSRS

Tags: list, infopath, reporting-services

I have a challenging question from my manager.

In InfoPath/SharePoint, he is trying to capture the time spent by his team on various activities via SharePoint.

Using an infopath form, each week his  team fills out a “Time Spend” form capturing category (Project, Support, Work Request, Other), and software (SAP, Basware, .Net, etc..). This could be several lines, as they jump from project to project, or over to support to put out the latest fire.

Manager uses this information to dissect where they are spending our time as a group, using excel pivot tables now, but would like to use SSRS.

Manager would like to discuss with me "how you would do this", "some of the challenges you see",  "how long it might take to develop the infopath, sharepoint, and SSRS reports".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expose the InfoPath form key fields via content types published from the InfoPath form, you can use SSRS against the SharePoint List.  This is quite simple in SSRS 2008 R2.